# Can I customize a Google Maps layer in terms of content?

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps

I don't want all features that come with the Google street layer. I just want basic infrastructure like roads, national parks, cities, streets with their names, etc. Everything that is public is OK. I don't want private companies and shops to appear on the map.

I am using OpenLayers to display the Google Maps street layer. So maybe it's possible to choose what to display by using the Google Maps API instead of OpenLayers..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  See [this thread](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Google-v3-Styles-Maps-in-OpenLayers-td3919926.html#a3919931) from 2010.

Thread discusses how to do it in Google Maps natively and then how to do it via OpenLayers.

Comment: You're welcome! Is there a way to download google maps data or some of it as vector data (shp or anything I can turn into postgis tables)?  (Apart from using Google Earth Pro)

Comment: No, you can't download google data.  If you're looking for raw data, look into OpenStreetMap.  You will find many posts about it on this board as well.